# Read values from multiple radioButtonLists in a Grid

Tags: jquery, .net, radiobuttonlist

I am creating an attendance page where students are displayed in a grid and each student has to be marked as present, absent or on leave using radio buttons.

A screenshot of the attendance page :

[image]

I can only select the status from the first student with jQuery, not the other ones.

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('[id*=btnsave]').on('click', function() {
            var val = "";
            val = $('[id*=RBL1]').find('input:checked').val();
            if (val != "" && val != undefined) {
                alert("The value of the selected item is : " + val)
            }
            else {
                alert("No item in the RadioButton List Selected !!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I select the statuses of the other students using something like a loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should add a class to your radiobutton lists and iterate them, it should be something like this:

```
  $('.rbl').each(function() {
        var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked');
        if (checked.length == 0) {
            alert("No item in the RadioButton List Selected !!");
        }
        else{
            ......`enter code here`
        }

  });
```